# JSON full circle (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, json, apache, wampserver

I've reduced to the simplest form, and am still stumbling...I've spent more than 30 hours researching and testing.  According to all of the posts which never show more than 15° of the entire circle, this is supposed to be really easy.

I want to:

1. Send query parameters (in JSON) from an Android Phone to a WAMP server...This may be as much as a complete dump of a local SQLite table, so query strings just won't cut it.
2. Have the WAMP server read the JSON data, formulate a SQL query and submit to the mySQL database
3. Package a response as JSON data (from a simple "OK" to a full table dump)
4. Return the response package to the Android phone

This is already a fully functional WAMP application, and I want to integrate Android access.  For this reason, I *really* want to avoid AJAX, since I want to maintain consistency with what's already in place.

I've reduced this to the simplest loop and am hitting snags.  I'm using send.php to post some JSON data to receive.php.  At this point, I just need receive.php to read the data and send it back (slightly modified) to send.php

send.php is properly reading stock JSON sent from receive.php.  I just can't get any sign of life that receive.php even recognizes the JSON sent to it.

*PLEASE* don't direct me towards cURL...from everything I've found regarding Android and JSON, cURL is a tangent which will send me full circle back into nonfunctionality.

APACHE 2.2.22, PHP 5.4.3

Like I said, I've reduced this to the simplest form to demonstrate a full circle...

send.php:

```
<?php
$url = "http://192.168.0.102:808/networks/json/receive.php";
$data = array(
        'param1'      => '12345',
        'param2'    => 'fghij'
);
$json_data = json_encode($data);

$options = array(
        'http' => array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => $json_data,
                'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                "Accept: application/json\r\n" .
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_data) . "\r\n"
        )
);

$context  = stream_context_create( $options );
$result = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );

$response = json_decode( $result , true);
echo '[' . $response['param1'] . "]\n<br>";
//THIS WORKS!  send.php displays "Initialized"
?>
```

receive.php

```
<?php
$newparam = 'Initialized';
//HERE I NEED TO read the JSON data and do something

$data = array(
        'param1'      => $newparam,
        'param2'    => 'pqrst'
);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Inside receive.php use `error_log()` to look for signs of life.

Comment: @user2147564 Try json_decode($data) when you're reading (in receive.php) the JSON data that was sent.

Comment: isset($_POST) returns true, but seems to contain nothing.  If I try to access $_POST['content'], which seems logical from the header sent _by_ send.php, there's nothing there (error).  I know I'll need to json_decode($data_from_send_php), but how do I retrieve incoming JSON data?

Comment: Upon further testing, receive.php receives $_POST as an array, but count($_POST) = 0...The problem (to start) is send.php

Comment: Only took a couple of hundred posts to find it...Send was actually OK-It was properly sending the JSON data to receive.php.  JSON data was retrievable via "$data_from_send_php = file_get_contents('php://input');"

Answer (score 0):

It is actually easy, as stated in all the incomplete explanations...I got the full circle to work *finally*

I've chosen simplicity to prove I could travel full circle, and I have now done so.

send.php

```
<?php 
//The URL of the page that will:
//  1. Receive the incoming data
//  2. Decode the data and do something with it
//  3. Package the results into JSON
//  4. Return the JSON to the originator
$url = "http://192.168.0.102:808/networks/json/receive.php";

//The JSON data to send to the page (above)
$data = array(
        'param1'      => 'abcde',
        'param2'    => 'fghij'
);
$json_data = json_encode($data);

//Prep the request to send to the web site
$options = array(
        'http' => array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => $json_data,
                'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                "Accept: application/json\r\n"
        )
);
$context  = stream_context_create( $options );

//Make the request and grab the results
$result = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );

//Decode the results
$response = json_decode( $result , true);

//Do something with the results
echo '[' . $response['param1'] . "]\n<br>";
?>
```

receive.php

```
<?php
//K.I.S.S. - Retrieve the incoming JSON data, decode it and send one value 
//back to send.php

//Grab the incoming JSON data (want error correction)
//THIS IS THE PART I WAS MISSING
$data_from_send_php = file_get_contents('php://input');

//Decode the JSON data
$json_data = json_decode($data_from_send_php, true);

//CAN DO:  read querystrings (can be used for user auth, specifying the 
//requestor's intents, etc)

//Retrieve a nugget from the JSON so it can be sent back to send.php
$newparam = $json_data["param2"];

//Prep the JSON to send back
$data = array(
        'param1'      => $newparam,
        'param2'    => 'pqrst'
);

//Tell send.php what kind of data it is receiving
header('Content-type: application/json');

//Give send.php the JSON data
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

AND Android integration...called with a Button.onClickListener

```
public void getServerData() throws JSONException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    //Not critical, but part of my need...Preferences store the pieces to manage JSON
    //connections
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String netURL = prefs.getString("NetworkURL", "");
    //  "http://192.168.0.102:808/networks/json"
    String dataPage = prefs.getString("DataPage", "");
    //  "/receive.php"

    //NEEDED - the URL to send to/receive from...
    String theURL = new String(netURL + dataPage);

    //Create JSON data to send to the server
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("param1",Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.ANDROID_ID));
    json.put("param2","Android Data");

    //Prepare to commnucate with the server
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ResponseHandler <String> resonseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(theURL);

    //Attach the JSON Data
    postMethod.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));

    //Send and Receive
    String response = httpClient.execute(postMethod,resonseHandler);

    //Begin reading and working with the returned data
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response); 

    TextView tv_param1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_json_1);
    tv_param1.setText(obj.getString("param1"));
    TextView tv_param2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_json_2);
    tv_param2.setText(obj.getString("param2"));
    }
```